# MSVC: is it possible to enable specific language extensions (i.e. not all at once)?

Tags: c, visual-studio, visual-c++, user-experience, usability

Context: C compiler option [`/Ze`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/za-ze-disable-language-extensions?view=msvc-160) enables all [Microsoft extensions to C and C++](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/microsoft-extensions-to-c-and-cpp).

A simple question: is it possible to enable specific language extensions (i.e. not all at once)?

Comment: Nope. (This space is intentionally left blank)

Comment: You probably want to always use `/Ze` and enable all extensions. For at least one reason. From the link you posted, AFAICT, standard ANSI `//` single line comments are only supported as an extension??? Most other compilers support this by default (since the 1990s). Some of the other "extensions" seem to be things other compilers support, possibly with `-std=` or `-f*`. The ms compiler appears to default to a early/ancient version from the 1980s???

Comment: @CraigEstey Interesting guess. Quick test shows that `/Za` does not lead to issuing a diagnostics related to single-line comments. What may be critical: `/Za` leads to generation of intrinsics for `exp`, `sqrt`, etc., and these intrinsics do not set `errno`, which is required by the standard: "A domain error occurs ...".

Comment: A number of the other extensions are [IMO] dubious (e.g. `void foo(int a,...); void foo(int a,char *b) {}`). But, ones I actually use are: (1) _transparent union_: `struct bar { int able; union { int *x; long y; }; };  struct bar b = { .able = 23, .y = 17 };`. (2) _Unsized arrays as the last field in structures and unions_ I don't have access to the MS compiler, so I can't say which options are better. But, if it were me, I'd want support for the features I mentioned by whatever means. Does `/Zc:*`, `/permissive`, or `/std:*` provide better control?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`/Za` is super-ancient... ANSI 89. The `/Ze` flag is deprecated. Don't use either of them.

For modern language conformance, the `/Zc`, `/permissive-`, and `/std:*` switches are the way to go.

If you are looking for C rather than C++ conformance, see [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/overview/install-c17-support?view=msvc-160) for details on the new `/std:c11` and `/std:c17` switch in VS 2019 (16.8 or later).